# Can prime composites 5 and above reveal all possible primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am coming from base 12 music theory which I have been developing since 2011. I (re)discovered that columns 1, 5, 7 and 11 of the octave 0-11 contained all the prime numbers. Then that the other numbers in these four columns were composites only of primes 5 and above. Next that composites 5 and above could only be found in these four columns.

Conclusion: if a way can be found to eliminate all the composites from 5 on up in these four columns of the octave, this should reveal all the primes one after the other.

I found a way using multiplication that I think can eliminate all the composites created by primes 5 and above. This method has not yet been turned into a computer program, which should not be very complicated. It is not a mathematical formula, but an algorithm.

It seems to me that the method is consistent. Of course I could be wrong.

Would some of you read the two versions of my 'proof' and help determine its validity?

I am attaching a link to a folder where two pdf documents can be found. The first one dated 210207 has 13 pages, is more compact (4k), and uses abbreviations. The second one dated 210622 has 5 pages and uses plain English, is heavier (7k), covers the same but less ground, and is much easier to understand.

[enter link description here](https://app.box.com/s/8e7vvmtov9fgxixtefelcqun9ir3gbkh)

I am wondering does a method already exist to produce serially all prime numbers?

I am also wondering that if there was such a method would the powers that be find it acceptable, or would they consider it dangerous in some way? This because experts refuse to consider my work despite results that appear convincing.

Before you reject this post for wrong form, have a look at how it produces the composites that reveal the primes.

Here is a tentative redefinition of what is a prime. Primes are numbers that cannot be created when all numbers greater than 1 are added to themselves to infinity.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing a form of [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

Comment: And yes, methods exist to [generate the prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_primes).

Comment: Sieving methods are however very inefficient if the primes we want are in large ranges , say near $10^{30}$.

Comment: "when all numbers greater than 1 are added to themselves to infinity." This is quite confusing.

Comment: "I am wondering does a method already exist to produce serially all prime numbers?" Of course, we simply can check every number , one by one , whether it is prime. The sieve of Erathosthenes can find the primes below $n$ systematically , but for large $n$ it is not practical.

Comment: Just a comment about your 12 columns. The real phenomen is with 6 columns ; all prime numbers are in column 1 and 5. Your column 7 is column 1 and your column 11 is column 5. Why 6 ? Because  $2 \times 3=6=$ the product of the 2 first prime numbers. Exactly same phenomen exists with $2 \times 3 \times 5=30$ columns and primes are concentrated on columns $1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29$ or $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7=210$ columns or $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7\times 11=2310$ columns or etc etc

Comment: To Karl, No not a form of wheel factorization. Composites of 2 and 3 found only in the other 8 columns, not in 1 5 7 11. Their study of interest to me. So is prime number generation. To Peter, Yes, the comment is rubbish. The sieve used by Eras is probably decimal. No columns concentrate all the primes and all their composites 5 and up as in base 12, reducing operation numbers. Comparison needed. It is an improvement in Eras' method. To Lourrran, Agree entirely with you. I'm from music, why not base 12? All 12 keys treated exactly the same way. Only advantage of C Major: all white position.